# How can you tell where a particular instance of JCIFS is running?

Tags: jcifs

At my company, I have been getting locked out of my Windows account every morning for over a year. The company IS keeps telling me that a computer with the name `jcifs3_188_b5` is pushing a bad password every 20 minutes.

They also tell me that this is not a computer on the company network and just tell me to find the machine and make it stop doing that. So, there is a real detective job here since I have no idea what JCIFS is other than something that is pushing a bad password from my account every 20 minutes.

Where does a JCIFS system reside and why can no one figure out where it is coming from? Is there a tool to be able to find this out?

Answer (score 0):

The JCIFS application is likely running from the user's phone.  This program appears to be linked to a mobile mail program.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, unfortunately I am a dinosaur and do not have a phone with mail capability, and I also don't bring the phone into my office. Possibly due to shame. The passwords have to be coming from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently JCIFS contructs the workstation name from the IP address in this format:

```
JCIFS<3rd octet>_<4th octet>_<index>
```

So you should be able to track down the machine from that.